# python Variable in a string

Tags: python, string, variables, formatting

I am trying to specify a standard binary format length from a variable but for some reason it never works. Am I doing the formatting wrong or the variable inclusion?

```
comp.write("{0:%ib}".format(I) % num_bits)
```

> ValueError: Invalid conversion specification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, it's in the wrong order:

```
("{0:%ib}" % num_bits).format(I)
```

Secondly, this isn't the way to do it! Mixing up types of formatting operator implies you don't know it can be done together. You want:

```
"{:{}b}".format(I, num_bits)
```

and if you really want to do it in two steps:

```
"{{:{}b}}".format(num_bits).format(I)
```

The `{{` and `}}` are escaped, so are transformed to single braces, after the first `.format`.

Comment: "{:0{}b}".format(I, num_bits) was best answer. I forgot to include the leading zeros as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing the interpolation the wrong way round. You'll need to resolve the `%i` before passing it to `format`. This would work:

```
comp.write(("{0:%ib}" % num_bits).format(I))
```

but is pretty horrible, you probably want to split it into two:

```
fmt = "{0:%ib}" % num_bits
comp.write(fmt.format(I))
```

Comment: Is there an order of operations in python??

Comment: Do you mean operator precedence? Of course, but that's not relevant. The way you had it, the `%` operates on the result of the `format` call, rather than being passed to it.